# Author template help. How to check if field exists in the profile?

Tags: templates, author, author-template

I'm coding my author template.

I want something like this

```
<?php if(Author filled about me)) { ?>
                        <div class="title">About me</div>
                        <div class="descwrap">
                        <div class="descinner"><?php echo about me; ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
```

I tried this code. But its not working.

```
<?php if(isset($curauth->description)) { ?>
                        <div class="title">About me</div>
                        <div class="descwrap">
                        <div class="descinner"><?php echo $curauth->description; ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
```

CAn anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php if(!empty($curauth->description)) { ?>
   <div class="title">About me</div>
   <div class="descwrap">
       <div class="descinner">
          <?php echo $curauth->description; ?>
       </div>
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This should work for you. It checks if the variable is empty or not (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).